# Phrases to introduce an answer to a question?

Tags: phrase-request

What are some ways to offer a solution or answer to a question? For example, "Try this" or "How (or what?) about this".

I'm looking for some other idiomatic expressions in English that could be used when presenting an answer to a question (for example, on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Can you give a little more context or examples of a situation where you want to use these idioms?

Comment: For example providing code example on SOF.

Comment: ***One possibility*** is a closevote, on the grounds that there are many ways of prefacing an answer/response. It's all a matter of opinion, so there can be no "right" answer.

Comment: Surely, there is no exclusively right answer. I would like to know some most common expressions. Thank you for "one possibility", it is new for me.

Comment: Not sure why this is on hold -- seems like a reasonable request for some examples of phrasing that could be used to answer a question. I've edited to tighten up and clarify a little, but I think the general question is valid and the answers can provide useful information to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here's one possible solution:
>
> Give this a try:
>
> This worked for me:
>
> Have you tried something like this:
>
> You might consider this:

All of these are "softer" ways of presenting an answer, as opposed to more confidently (or arrogantly) saying, "Here's the answer..."  It all depends on the tone you want to convey.